# Modify Named Table in Excel File with Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to add columns to an existing table in an excel file.
Therefore I wan't to use python and the openpyxl library.

Right now I use a class when it is initialising, it is connecting to the file.
Afterwards I call the check_for_column function and when the column is not existing it should create it. And in the end of the script I save the file.

```path
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableColumn, range_boundaries
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter


class ExcelHandler:
    _wb_name = None
    _table = None
    _wb = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._wb_name = os.getenv('EXCEL_FULLPATH')
        self._wb = load_workbook(filename=self._wb_name, keep_vba=True)
        sheet = self._wb['DataInbox']
        self._table = sheet.tables['WebPageForms']
        return

    def check_for_column(self, column_name):

        if not column_name in self._table.column_names:
            lst_ids = [my_object.id for my_object in self._table.tableColumns]
            new_id = lst_ids[-1]+1

            # change range of table
            min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(
                self._table.ref)
            max_col += 1
            mx = get_column_letter(max_col)
            mn = get_column_letter(min_col)
            self._table.ref = '{}{}:{}{}'.format(mn, min_row, mx, max_row)

            # add column to table
            tc = TableColumn(id=new_id, name=column_name)
            self._table.tableColumns.append(tc)

        return

    def save_wb(self):
        self._wb.save(self._wb_name)
        return
```

The code runs fine as shown. Although when I then try to open the file with excel it gives me an alert saying:

*We found a problem with some content in ’file.xlsm’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.*

This is the repair result of excel when I press yes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>Repair Result to file.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file ’*path*/file.xlsm’</summary><repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:"><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)</repairedRecord></repairedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I would highly appreciate If anyone could help me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem why the excel file is corrupt, my bad.
when I create the column in the table, I also have to write the name in the respective cell:

```
    def check_for_column(self, column_name):

            ***

            # write name in cell of new column header
            self._ws.cell(row=min_row, column=max_col).value = column_name

            ***

        return
```

If I add this to the code, my table is modified correctly